# Using dplyr mutate_at to change specified list of variables with case_when statement

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to recode some columns in a data set. The columns have a lot of weird names like S3__8 or C4__2. There are also some categorical columns I want to leave alone that start with C like Case.

I used this segment to successfully recode all of the S columns:

```
Sa_Recode <- Sa %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("S")),
    funs(case_when(grepl("Yes", ., ignore.case = TRUE) ~ "1",
                   grepl("No", ., ignore.case = TRUE) ~ "0",
                   grepl("Some", ., ignore.case = TRUE) ~ "0.5",
                   TRUE                                         ~ "Else")))
```

I want to recode the C columns, but can't use the same logic because some of my other columns start with C.
I've tried editing the mutate line like this with no luck:

Creating a list of the columns I need and making a list

```
list <- c('C1_(*)__', 'C2_4__', 'C3_(*)__', 'C3a_(*)__') 
mutate_at(vars(list),
```

Listing them as variables

```
mutate_at(c('C1_(*)__', 'C2_4__', 'C3_(*)__', 'C3a_(*)__'),
```

Listing them differently as variables

```
mutate_at(vars(c('C1_(*)__', 'C2_4__', 'C3_(*)__', 'C3a_(*)__')),
```

Calling a range of columns

```
mutate_at(Sa[,8:53],
```

I'll be repeating this process with about nine other sets (with different starting letters) and am hoping to learn how to manipulate the logic.
Alternatively, is there a way to make the "else" in the case statement not recode the value? This could also fix the issue.
Thanks!

```
Sample Input:
Case  S25_    S26_(*)__   C1_(*)__
A     No      Some        Yes
B     Yes     Skipped     Yes
C     No      N/A         Some

Desired output:
Case  S25_    S26_(*)__   C1_(*)__
A     0       0.5         1
B     1       Skipped     1
C     0       N/A         0.5
```

Comment: please include some representative input and expected output data using `dput` for instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to correctly identify columns that you want to change.

```
library(dplyr)
Sa %>%
  mutate_at(vars(matches('^S|C\\d+')),
             ~case_when(grepl("Yes", ., ignore.case = TRUE) ~ "1",
                        grepl("No", ., ignore.case = TRUE) ~ "0",
                        grepl("Some", ., ignore.case = TRUE) ~ "0.5",
                        TRUE ~ "Else"))
```

This will select columns which start with `"S"` or which has `"C"` followed by a number.

Also `mutate_at` has been replaced with `across` so you can now use :

```
Sa %>%
   mutate(across(matches('^S|C\\d+'),
            ~case_when(grepl("Yes", ., ignore.case = TRUE) ~ "1",
                       grepl("No", ., ignore.case = TRUE) ~ "0",
                       grepl("Some", ., ignore.case = TRUE) ~ "0.5",
                       TRUE ~ "Else")))
```

Comment: Thank you! However, this isn't working for the C columns. I tried splitting it into two (one mutate_at with S first then another with C first, but it recoded Case.

Comment: Don't split the columns. Can you show what you have in `names(Sa)` ?

Comment: "Case_First_Name"
 [7] "Case_Last_Name"  "S5_(*)__"        "S5a_(*)__"       "S5b_"            "Text...11"       "S6_(*)__" 
[13] "S7_"             "S8_(*)__"        "S9_(*)__"        "S10_"            "Text...17"       "S11_(*)__" 
[19] "S12_(*)__"       "S12a_(*)__"      "S13_(*)__"       "S14_(*)__"       "Text...23"       "S15_(*)__" 
[37] "S24_(*)__"       "S25_"            "S26_(*)__"       "C1_(*)__"        "C2_(*)__"        "S18_(*)__"      
[49] "S3_(*)__"        "Text...50"       "S4_(*)__"        "C3_(*)__"        "C3a_(*)__"       "CASE_P"

Comment: I had to delete some, but they're similar in name, some have asterisks, some don't. There's also some "Text..." columns I don't need to recode

Comment: Then you can just use `matches('^S|C\\d+')`. Check updated answer.

Comment: If I run into a scenario with three letters, would it change to: matches('^S|C|A\\d+')

Comment: yes, you can use `|` to add different combinations of patterns.

Comment: Hey, sorry I'm back, but is there a way to do this with a range of columns? I had one table that had this many versions `mutate_at(vars(matches('^RS|E|C|CDT|S\\d+'))` and it in turn recoded the whole table. I just need it done for `df[,12:ncol(df)]`

Comment: You can specify column by position as well in `mutate_at` : `Sa %>% mutate_at(12:ncol(df), ....rest of the code`.